# Как сделать свой браузер на основе исходного кода chromium?

Tags: chromium

Знаю, где лежит исходный код, знаю что можно и что переделывали (на некоторых форумах судя по-всему это делал каждый 2-ой, хотя по-моему это бред), но не знаю как переделать и поэтому прошу выдать ссылки на материал или обучающий сайт, где объяснят как сделать свой браузер на основе исходного кода chromium.

Comment: Уточните - а что Вы понимаете под своим браузером? Ведь хром - это не только браузер, а еще и система плагинов, котрые лежат на гугл-хостинге, профили, интегрированные с гуглом, и еще множество сервисов, котрые работают благодаря тому, что хром - это браузер, собранный гглом и опирающийся на его экосистему. Ок, теперь есть свободный хромиум. Та всего, что я перечислил - нет. А теперь вы говорите "я хочу еще один, мой браузер". Чем же он будет отличаться?

Comment: @S.H. [хостинг плагинов](https://github.com/NeverDecaf/chromium-web-store) относится не к браузеру

Comment: Сначала попробуйте сделать сборку [готового браузера](https://github.com/Eloston/ungoogled-chromium). Сама сборка браузера идет от 4х часов до 2-3 суток. В зависимости от производительности вашей машины. А вот на настройку всего мероприятия сборки у вас уйдут месяцы

Comment: @S.H. Свой браузер роднее, там встроенный блекжек, красивая иконка, бросское название...

Comment: Нет, мне нужен именно клон chromium (потому что меня, мягко говоря, не устраивает браузер из Visual studio за 5 минут) и минимальные изменения в нём, такие, как (цитирую @DiD): _встроенный блекжек, красивая иконка, бросское название..._

Comment: @DiD - насчет хостинга плагинов: спасибо за инфу, не знал!

Comment: @S.H. И все же я немного некорректно выразил мысль. Я хотел просто отметить факт существования версии отдельной от проприетарных сервисов Google. В обычном хромиуме есть ссылка на "магазин расширений", но без навязанной рекламы оных, при этом расширения хостящиеся у гугла полностью рабочие и устанавливается в один клик. Есть ребята, которые поддерживают версии без упоминаний гугла в коде.

Comment: Что касается вопроса автора, конечно вопрос очень общий, лишен деталей. Я бы посоветовал обратить внимание на [electron](https://www.electronjs.org/). Тот же браузер, только не надо полностью собирать из исходников. Собирается в единый файл очень легко, на основе electron есть много [браузеров](https://www.electronjs.org/apps?q=Browser).